# Analyse abstract data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, bigdata

I need to process a lot of csv files that contains 3 columns: date, tv channel id, movie id.

Based on those columns, i need to classify what is the genre of each movie and the genre of tv channel id.

I'm new to big data process and i was wondering how can i classify that data if i only have an id (i can not use another source to search the id or generate random data to train my algorithm).

The solution that i found is define some range of hours and put the films that are on range inside some genre. Example:

- movies that are played between 01:00-04:00, genre 1;
- movies that are played between 04:01-06:00, genre 2;
- etc.

After classify movies, i can classify the tv channels based on movies that they have played.

And i'm planning to do it using Spark :)

Anyone have another solution or any advice? It's kinda hard because those data looks like só abstract.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some code that you've tried? As it stands, there are so many approaches that the question is too broad to answer.

Comment: From your explanation, it seems, you are still figuring out the business logic!!! Once you figure out the business logic, how spark can be used can be thought through.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I need to classify the genre of the movie", do you mean "Drama", "Comedy", "Action", or "Genre1", "Genre2"? I would suppose the second case in the following.

**Don't assign a genre by hand - Use a clustering algorithm**

First, I won't assign a genre based only on the time when the movie is played. Generally speaking, I would prevent you from doing the clustering by hand. As this is what clustering algorithms are made for. Those use features to group individuals that are, in a way, related one to each other.

In your case, there is a tricky part : each data point/row is not a movie. Thus, a movie might be present in different clusters, meaning having different genres.

There are several options :

- Either a movie belons to different genres - which is quite natural.
- You can choose only one genre based on the group where the movie appears the most frequently
- If you decide to assign multiple genre per movie, you might think of a thresholds : for instance, if a movie appears less than N times in a group, then it does not belong to this group (unless it is the only groups it appears)

**Create new features**

You should design as *much new features** as you can, helping the clustering algorithm to separate the data well and create homogeneous clusters.

As I can think of, you can do :

- Add an boolean feature for each time frame you consider (0:00 - 3:59 ; 4:00 - 6:00 ; ... ). Only one of these features is one : when the movie is played. The others are null.
- A feature counting how many times the movie has been played (*Men in Black* is more played than *12 Angry Men*))
- A feature couting how many channel ID have played this movie (*Star Wars* is played on more channel than some Bollywood movie)
- ...

Think of how a genre is represented / played throughout all channels and create the featuers accordingly.

PS: * Don't get me wrong, *as much features* means more than your three features but what's called the curse of dimensionality.

Comment: You give good advice but this question isn't really appropriate for StackOverflow, it is better suited for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @IgorQA Thank you for amazing advices. I only can have "Genre1", "Genre2", etc because i only have "random" numbers on my CSV file. Now i have a (silly) question, when you say to create new features, do you mean to create it on my clustering algorithm? This is my first time doing it, i was running in a circles before your advices.

Comment: Out of your first three variables, create $N$ new features such as the one I mentionned. Then, perform your clustering algorithm on your total 3 + N features